# Bing Map throws exception in 'Windows Runtime Component' project

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, c++-cx, bing-maps

First of all I want to apologize for the English.
I'am develop windows 8.1 store app. On C++/CX language. My solution contains several projects. One of projects has the *'Windows Runtime Component'* type, and perform geocoding and reverse geocoding.
For a geocoding I use 'Bing Maps SDK for Windows 8.1 Store apps'([link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1)).
Here's my algorithm:

```
void addressByLocation(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    ResourceLoader^ loader = ref new ResourceLoader();
    String^ credentials = loader->GetString("BingMapCredentials");

    Location^ location = ref new Location(latitude, longitude);
    ReverseGeocodeRequestOptions^ requestOptions = ref new ReverseGeocodeRequestOptions(location);

    Map^ map = ref new Map();
    map->Credentials = credentials;

    SearchManager^ searchManager = map->SearchManager;
    task<LocationDataResponse^> reverseGeocodeTask(searchManager->ReverseGeocodeAsync(requestOptions));
    reverseGeocodeTask.then([=](LocationDataResponse^ response)
    {
        if (!response->HasError)
        {
        //
        }
    });
}
```

I've got the problem in this line:

```
Map^ map = ref new Map();
```

It always generates an exception with text:
**"Platform::DisconnectedException ^ at memory location 0x0396DF80.
 
HRESULT:0x80010108 The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

WinRT information: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients."**

*But I noticed something weird. If add project to the solution which contains UI(xaml), my code in this project works perfectly fine, without any exceptions.*
Can somebody specify an error to me?
 Or give the explanation for this strange behavior.
 
There is probably other methods to perform geocoding for windows 8.1 store apps, which I don't know yet.
Thanks.

Comment: If you do not use the `Windows Runtime Component`, does it throw the exception? Also what is the solution which contains? Do you mean you add the addressByLocation method in the Windows Runtime Component and there is no UI in it?

Comment: Hello @Jayden. My solution contains one Blank App(Windows) project, and a few Windows Runtime Component(Windows) projects. In Blank App  code of 'addressByLocation' works good. But in Windows Runtime Component(without UI) code of  'addressByLocation' throws the exception.